# Algebraic proof involving Independent Set Problem & Maximum Degree

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, algorithms

I was wondering if somebody could help me with a graph-related proof!

Let:

- $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph;
- $S \subseteq V$ a maximal independent set;
- $\Delta$ the maximum degree of the graph ( = the maximum number of edges any vertex has).

I strongly suspect that $\Delta \geq \frac{|S|}{|V \setminus S|}$ for a certain category of graphs, like *non-trivial connected graphs* perhaps; however I'm struggling to prove it and yielded poor results so far.

What do you guys think, can this be (dis)proved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true for all connected graphs on more than $1$ vertex. (Or, for an even weaker assumption, all graphs with no isolated vertices.)

Let $S$ be a maximal independent set. Each vertex of $S$ must be adjacent to some vertex of $V \setminus S$, since otherwise it wouldn't be connected to anything.

This gives us at least $|S|$ edges incident to $|V\setminus S|$ vertices, so one of the vertices must be incident to at least $\frac{|S|}{|V\setminus S|}$ of them.

Comment: It took me a bit to visualize the last statement but I think I got it: would it be rightfully justified with the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: That's the idea, yes.